FBX exported armature animation goes haywire when scale is animated
I have a complex character rig done by me in Blender and the models based on it imported seemingly nicely into Unity. I unfortunately can't share the model or its image by now.
Things start to go awry when I animate paws' scale and put arms stretch-and-squash into the mix: they animate as expected within Blender, with scales transfering when set to, but the exported model stretch horrifically in Unity, like all scales and stretches started to build-up one on top of the other with no compensation for parents transforms or else.
I have tried to export the model in different ways, including Apply Transforms on and off and changing the way scale is transfered to involved bones (Properties > Bone > Relations > Inherit Scale set to None and others), but nothing seems to work.
I haven't tried yet anything with Relative Parenting (Properties > Bone > Relations > Relative Parenting) due to time pressure and I've just removed squash-and-stretch and scale from the animation for now.
The problem is not in Unity, as reimporting the FBX model into Blender shows the exact same problem. So: exported FBX != Blender animated model.
All search I do lead me to other kind of common Blender-to-Unity scale problem (namely the 0.01 scale factor in the entire thing), but that's something I've already got right.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Exporter settings (which give correct orientation and correct skeleton scale withing Unity):
✔ Selected Objects
> Transform
    Scale: 1.0
    Apply Scalings: FBX Units Scale
    Forward: -Z Forward
    Up: Y Up
    ✔ Apply Unit
    ✔ Use Space Transform
    ✔ Apply Transform ⚠
> Armature
    Primary Bone Axis: +Y Axis
    Secondary Bone Axis: X Axis
    Armaure FBXNode Type: Null
    ✔ Only Deform Bones
    ✔ Add Leaf Bones
> ✔ Animation
    ✔ Key All Bones
    ✔ NLA Strips
    ✔ All Actions
    ✔ Force Start/End Keying
    Sampling Rate: 1.0
    Simplify: 1.0


The problem might not be in Unity, but it is not in Blender either. FBX is not a Blender-specific format, so not everything you do in Blender might be compatible with the FBX file format and therefore not be exported as expected. Of course re-importing it in Blender will then show the same issues, because Blender cannot say "oh, this file was originally created here with things that work in Blender, let's see if I can restore them from the 'broken' FBX data."

Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8PSj_1-E9uY

@GordonBrinkmann I can't agree. While I have lots of constraints that just weren't carried over due to obvious incompatibilities, Blender's sampled the transforms for every frame and I ordered it to apply transforms. The final transforms do not reflect world transforms for every bone as they aren't being applied to their local space per frame. And I've got those stretches right in 3dsmax a decade ago, so they're possible.

@joshsanfelici I sort of figured out I'd have to do that, after so much animation done, but was resisting it. Reality knocks the door. Thanks for the video!
